# Retrieve unstable content in Crome extention

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I get  content of a downloaded page in Chrome extension. Mostly content is retrieved wholly, but on some pages it returns 39 symbols. And on my observation it doesn't depend on the size of these pages.
For instance, I get length of the page https://clockify.me/ in the size of 30475, the page https://clockify.me/time-management-techniques - 39.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon-16.png",
      "32": "images/icon-32.png",
      "36": "images/icon-36.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32.png",
    "36": "images/icon-36.png"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="size"></div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    document.getElementById('size').innerHTML = request.source.length;
  }
});

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id, allFrames: true },
    files: ['cscript.js']
  });
});
```

cscript.js

```
var s = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getSource", source: s });
```